# Why 1.00 is bigger than 10 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Recently I have noticed MySQL number problem.

In my case if I will create simple select, example: `account_balance > a.cpc` where `account_balance` is `10` and cpc is `1.00`, then somehow `cpc` is higher value.

Full code:

`SELECT id WHERE account_balance > cpc LIMIT 1`

```
id |    cpc  |   account_balance  |
 1 |    1.00 |                10  |
```

This select should print `1`, now it prints nothing.

How I can fix it?

Comment: Can you explain the problem with the given query? To me, everything looks pretty clear

Comment: @NicoHaase For me also, but I don't know why MySQL cannot get this row.

Comment: What are the respective data types of `cpc` and `account_balance`?

Comment: Could it be that you are actually comparing character data?

Comment: So, please add more details like the table structure, and sample data for that table

Comment: @BenM `cpc` is `text`, `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and `account_balance` the same

Comment: Well, there's your problem. You should really be using numeric types for those fields.